# Does "pig" (fat animal) come from the Latin "pinguedo" (fat)?

Tags: etymology, latin, animals

Does "[pig](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/143654)" (fat animal) come from the Latin [*pinguedo*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17045/576) (fat)?

Comment: ***pig***: 
Middle English pigge "a young pig" (mid-13c., late 12c. as a surname), probably from Old English *picg, found in compounds, but, like dog, its further etymology unknown. https://www.etymonline.com/word/pig

Comment: @66974 Thanks for not giving this basic research as an 'answer'. There is a school on ELU that would censure 'answers in comments', but I think it's far worse, far less in tune with ELU's objectives, to encourage questions lacking reasonable basic research.

Comment: I did do research. I linked to the _OED_ and Lewis & Short, neither etymologies of which say there's any connection.

Comment: @user66974: How about Dutch *big* "piggy"? Unrelated?

Comment: If you've done research, you should state in the question what research you've done and what you found out.

Comment: For many people (and certainly in ELU's list of recommended resources) the go-to resource for investigating a word's etymology is the [Online Etymology Dictionary {hereafter 'Etymon'}. This will quickly provide an answer here](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pig). It is very unlikely that conflicting answers from other reputable sources (Etymon actually quotes from OED here) will be found.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Latin word, 'pinguedo' is the noun formed from the adjective 'pinguis', meaning 'fat'.  But, says Lewis and Short's Latin Dictionary, the root of this word is the verb 'pango', whose root, in turn relates to Greek 'παχος (pachos)', meaning 'stout'.  Of course, pigs are fat and are a source of fat.  But the Latin word for 'pig' was, as we all recognise, 'porcus'.  'Pinguedo' itself meant 'fatness', 'richness' and 'abundance' (post Augustan, and found in Pliny and Quintilian).

Comment: @Geremia *"I did do research. I linked to the OED and Lewis & Short, neither etymologies of which say there's any connection."* It is therefore surprising that you should ask the question...

Comment: Let's not forget that **porcine** comes from Latin, too. So many porcine people in the world today, right? :)

Comment: As the etymology of "pig" is readily available, from many sources, question downvoted. While that etymology is very indefinite, I saw no mentions of a Latin root. Given this, even if the question were asked **because** of that lack of definition, any answers would be highly speculative. At the moment I can't see this as useful, or researched.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Why would you say that? I find etymologies different from the (possibly outdated) OED's on a regular basis.

Comment: @MarkGB: You don't know that. There are many different etymological dictionaries in many languages, many treating Germanic words and cognates.

Comment: @Cerberus_RM OED is highly respected and would, right or wrong, be eminently suitable as a cited source on ELU for etymology. Etymon being so easily available, this would have been obvious research to show. Mitch does the LMGTFY which doesn't add to site credibility.  (Neither does the excursion into Latin etymology.) You could perhaps have added a really good answer.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica Actually, I DO know precisely what I claimed to know. Of several etymological sources I cross-checked, all were as described. That was a quick google and the top sources found. The sources OP used were similar. For my search, Wikipedia showed up, of course, but it references  the Online Etymology Dictionary, which is a highly-regarded source. Merriam-Webster also showed up, as I recall. If you know of any sources that have something else to show, please feel free to bring them to the discussion.

Comment: @MarkGB: I consulted De Vaan and Philippa in this case, which I consider better sources in general, when Philippa has something to say about the English cognate (which is usually the case, as now).

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica I'm familiar with De Vaan, but what is Philippa's work you consulted?

Comment: @Geremia: M. Philippa, F. Debrabandere, A. Quak, T. Schoonheim en N. van der Sijs (2003-2009) *Etymologisch Woordenboek van het Nederlands*, Amsterdam. Usually has better and more uptodate etymologies than English dictionaries. Goes back as far it can, to Proto-Indo-European or substrate languages. Seems to include latest research.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica Thanks. Is this the online version: https://www.etymologie.nl/ ?

Comment: @Geremia: That is where it can be consulted, yes. The site gives results from many etymological dictionaries at once.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica That's very nice. Thank you for bringing a new source. Perhaps you could tell us what they have to add, concerning the etymology of "*pig*"?

Comment: @MarkGB: Philippa et al. are uncertain about the ultimate origin of (modern, common) Dutch *big* "piggy". They say the conexion with English *pig* is likely, but uncertain (despite the similar meanings), because of the unexplained sound changes. There is a multitude of variations of the word (they give many examples); they say that such unexplained variations are often(?) the result of borrowing from a substrate language. This, in combination with relatively limited spread of the word (they mention Lower Saxony and coastal provinces), suggests a substrate language, c.q. non-Indo-European.

Comment: I see. Then they really add nothing to what we've already found in previous sources mentioned. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no evidence that Modern English 'pig' is derived or even cognate to Classical Latin 'pinguedo'.

[Etymonline gives the accepted history of 'pig' as:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pig)

> Middle English pigge "a young pig" (mid-13c., late 12c. as a surname), probably from Old English *picg, found in compounds, but, like dog, its further etymology unknown. The older general word for adults was swine, if female, sow, if male, boar. Apparently related to Low German bigge, Dutch big ("but the phonology is difficult" -- OED).

Semantically the 13 c 'pigge' drifted from a small swine to all sizes, and modern pronunciation 'pig' has the connotation of fat now since most modern adult pigs are bred to be fat.

In Latin 'pinguedo' is derived from 'pinguis' which means 'dull, stupid, fat'. Semantically, yes, the Latin original. word has drifted into 'fat'.

However, there is no historical evidence of any sound change, if 'pinguedo' were borrowed in any time of history of English (even back to the Roman occupation of Britain), that the sound changes at any of those time would have naturally led to changing the two syllable 'pinguo' to 'pig'.

---

Here are some details about borrowings and sound changes (I'll be abusing notation in the use of spelling for sound. as it makes things easier to write).
What we're looking for is the word 'pinguedo' or other derivations of pinguo' in Classical Latin or any derived variety (dialects of Italian, Spanish, French) from before the time 'pig' first appeared in English. Mid 13th c really says Old French or classical Latin would be an obvious source.

Since word initial 'p' and stressed (or single syllable word) 'i' are fairly stable in English from Old to Modern, they don't rule out a borrowing from Latin or Romance.

What makes an unlikely borrowing is the '-ngu-' /ŋg/ or /ŋgw/ in Latin/Romance. If borrowed, it is unlikely that English would drop the /ŋ/. Every word in OE with word final /ŋ/ (really /ŋg/) **maintains** it, instead of dropping it as what should happen to get
pingue -> pig. This is the primary reason not to believe a relation between the Latin word and the English one.

Proving a negative is much harder than proving a positive (for a positive just show the example, for a negative you have to appeal to a lot of rules that don't seem to work and in linguistics there can always be a one-off exception). And one of this says that the Latin source is impossible, but it since there's no direct positive evidence of a link (written used words), we have to work with likelihood and the strongest data points to 'no connection'.

Comment: This answer could be improved immensely by giving the sound change rules that would be relevant, showing that they did not in fact apply.

Comment: How is the answering of this question justifiable?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The forebears of 'pig' are unknown and this is an attempt at showing -how- the connection hypothesized is unlikely, which explanation doesn't seem likely to be documented.

Comment: @Mitch Given the purpose of your answer, I would recommend one minor edit. In the paragraph beginning "*Semantically*", I would edit thusly: "*and **today** has the connotation of fat, since . . .*". This would be for clarity, in that perceiving pigs as fat is a modern phenomena, which you noted by using "*now*", but I think it needs a bit more focus. Personally, I agree with Edwin that the question doesn't rate an answer, as, since generations of etymologists have found no relation to 'pinguedo' to document, there is, ipso facto, nothing TO document.

Comment: @MarkGB “Thusly”? I would edit your comment thus: “thus”.

Comment: @David, Pretty sure that would be grammatically incorrect.